# Solr 4 backup with replication handler

Tags: solr, backup, replication

I would like to backup my solr 4.8 index periodically by using

```
 curl http://localhost:8983/solr/gettingstarted/replication?command=backup
```

I don't understand if it is mandatory to build a master-slave architecture or if it sufficient to configure Replication RequestHandler on the Master/stand-alone Server.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it works as a standalone server: I configured the Replication RequestHandler and then I'm able to backup cores while they are running.

Comment: How would you configure replication endpoint in case of standalone solr? Can you please provide some reference?